# How to upload Files to Amazon S3 bucket and maintain versions

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, file-io, amazon-s3, cloud

I am stuck in middle of the development for the application which takes backup of some folders automatically everyday and have to implement and maintain different versions of files

For example:

1. Backup was started on 1 April 11 PM for the first time which uploaded 10 files
2. on 2nd April, 2 more files were added and 1 existing file was updated
3. Likewise everyday the backup will upload all the files automatically
4. On 10th April, user wants to get the files of 1st April only because the file which were uploaded on 1st April was good and out of that files, 1 of the file got corrupted

I don't want to re-upload all the same files on S3 bucket or some cloud drive if the file isn't updated but I do want to maintain the versions of the files.

How can I achieve it without re-uploading the file which is not changed and yet have the ability to restore the previous days version.

Thanks in advance for your help!!!!

Comment: Just enable versioning in the S3 bucket? http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/Versioning.html

Comment: Thanks @MarkB. But after enabling versioning on S3 bucket, can we get the files from previous / current versions using C#??

Comment: Yes, previous versions are available through use of the AWS SDK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found amazing ready code [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/131678/Amazon-S-Sync)

Hope this helps!!!